# Counting Items in JSON result

Tags: php, json

I am counting the amount of rows is my JSON result
however I am also trying to count the number of items in the result.

The row count works but the item count won't.
Getting error : Trying to get property of non-object on the $FLCount line

Code is below

```
// Counts The Rows - WORKS 
$row = $obj->response->result->Accounts->row;
$countRows = count($row);

// Counts The FL Items ( Doesn't Work )
$FLCount= $obj->response->result->Accounts->row->FL;
$countItems = count($FLCount);
```

JSON Result Snippet

```
{
  "response": {
    "result": {
      "Accounts": {
        "row": [
          {
            "no": "1",
            "FL": [
              {
                "val": "ITEM 1",
                "content": "XX"
              },
             {
                "val": "ITEM 2",
                "content": "XX"
              },
              {
                "val": "ITEM 3",
                "content": "XX"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `FL` is not a direct child of `row` so you need to access it by either looping `row` and accessing `FL` or hard-coding a row position `$obj->response->result->Accounts->row[0]->FL;`

Comment: See the ***Accessing nested items*** section of  [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29308899/2191572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$FLCount= $obj->response->result->Accounts->row[0]->FL;

$countItems = count($FLCount);
```

Comment: ahh keep forgetting the [0] bit

Answer (score 1):

You have the error because `$obj->response->result->Accounts->row` is not an object but an array of rows.

To count all items no matter the row you can just loop through the rows and add up the number of items in each :

```
// Counts The Rows - WORKS 
$rows = $obj->response->result->Accounts->row;
$countRows = count($rows);

// Counts The FL Items ( Doesn't Work )
$countItems = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $countItems += count($row->FL);
}
```

Comment: dont need to loop through all rows as the item count is the same in each row

Comment: oh. Then you could just do $couldItems = $countRows * count($obj->response->result->Accounts->row[0]->FL);

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT: Unfortunately, I've misunderstood your requirement, and my answer addresses the solution to count it in `JAVASCRIPT`, instead of `php`)

## 1st problem:

One is `array`, another is `object`. In such cases, you can use:

```
element.length
```

instead of

```
count(element)
```

## 2nd problem:

Your actual problem is nicely expressed by user @niiwig !  However, to make it shorter, use:

```
var amount=0; JSON.parse(YOUR_RESPONSE).response.result.Accounts.row.every((obj) => amount += obj.FL.length  );
```

and `amount` variable will have the correct number.